# click event with a for loop through an array only gives me the last item?

Tags: jquery, arrays, for-loop

I have an array:

```
var bar = [];
```

I have a for loop going through the array:

```
            for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
                $(".left-lg").find(".name").html(bar[i].name);
            }
```

I am trying to replace the content of the DIV.name with the content in the array, it works but only gives me the last one in the array.  I read, on a click event with javascript the loop will be at the end, so that is why.

Any way how to correct this so it will go through the entire loop and not just give the last one?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. If your array is `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`, what do you expect to be the contents of your div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're always setting the HTML content of *all* the elements matching `.name`. Try using the `index` argument supplied to [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) instead:

```
$(".left-lg .name").each(function(index) {
    $(this).html(bar[index].name);
});
```

Comment: seems like if i try this with other elements in the DOM it does not work: $(p.total).each(function(index){$(this.html(bar[index].countTotal;}); because i have other items in the array i need to put in??  Why would it only work on the first one?

Comment: There are syntax errors in that code (it should be `$(this).html(bar[index].countTotal);`). Maybe that's the problem? Or maybe you only have one item in your array?

Answer (score 0):

Try using append instead of html
`$(".left-lg").find(".name").append(bar[i].name);`

Answer (score 0):

Thats because everytime you call:

```
$(".left-lg").find(".name").html(bar[i].name);
```

you are overwriting your previous loops.

Set a variable equal to the values you want in an array, then pass that array to the element:

```
var allNames;

for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    allNames = allNames + bar[i].name);
}

$(".left-lg").find(".name").html(allNames);
```